# How to extract image urls from HTML File in C#

Tags: c#, .net, html, parsing, extract

Can anyone help me by explaining  how to extract image urls from HTML File in C#

Answer (score 31):

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) can do this - just use a query like //img and access the src - like so:

```
string html;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    html = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
}
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();        
doc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach(HtmlNode img in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")) {
    Console.WriteLine(img.GetAttributeValue("src", null));
}
```

Comment: +1 I painfully wrote a SO vote counter/tag using Regex yesterday. This would have helped a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a regex?

Comment: Will this only extract img elements that are children of the topmost node?

Comment: @mirezus - no the // means any level

Comment: That would not work very well in case of inline images as the SRC would actually contain the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the HTML and check the img tag use the following link it includes C# library for parsing HTML tags i faced your problem b4 and i used this library and working well with me [Parsing HTML tags](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/10918_2230091_2)