# Get files from web directory

Tags: c#, getfiles

I wanted to just get random Images from `http://random.cat/`, so I wanted to index them using `Directory.GetFiles` or something like that, but this doesn't work. So what would be the best way to get the functionality of `Directory.GetFiles` but for `http://random.cat/i` (this is where the Images are stored, I think)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **do not have access** to the images database but they provide an api to retrieve one image at a time.

Create a basic model:

```
public class RandomImage
{
    public string file { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use WebClient to do that:

```
public string RandomImage()
{
    string result = null;

    var apiurl = "http://random.cat";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiurl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = client.GetAsync(apiurl + "/meow").Result; // The .Result part will make this method not async
    if (ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var ResponseData = ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var MyRandomImage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RandomImage>(ResponseData);

        result = MyRandomImage.file; // This is the url for the file
    }

    // Return
    return result;
}
```

Call the function from your methods:

```
var MyImage = RandomImage();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was, what my issue was!

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.GetFiles()` is designed to be used on a filesystem, not on web addresses.

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bay1b5dh(v=vs.110).aspx) ought to be enough to get you started. Since you don't know the actual URL of the picture, you would have to [parse the page to find it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790559/how-to-extract-image-urls-from-html-file-in-c-sharp) and then make a further request to download it.

Be aware that they might block you out if you download too many images in a certain time.

EDIT: I noticed just now that they have an API, which makes everything a bit simpler. But it's marked as temporary, so make of that what you will.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you have to use HttpClient. I dont know any method for listing all files, but this also needs to be set up in the web server hosting the site.